# Call customized bash function in Python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, sh

I have searched online a lot and failed to find the exact workaround for this question. My question is that I would like to call a customized function in python. Say, I have written a bash function in my .bashrc

`

```
cpput2(){
    # 1 job name
    # 2 hpss pat
    # 3 filepath
    bsub -N -n 1 -q hpss -W 24:00 -P CWWW0001 -J $1 hsi "cd $2; cput -R $3"  
}
```

`

Is there any way to call it in python? os.system cannot find this function even I put it into my bashrc.

Comment: `.bashrc` is intended to customize your interactive shells, not serve as a library for other programs. If you need to run `bsub -N ...` from your Python script, make the call explicitly.

Comment: Or, create a script that runs the desired `bsub` command, and put it in a directory found in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute commands in bash over the command option `-c`. To make the function available in bash, you must include the source file with the dot command first, e.g.:

```
bash -c '. file.sh && cpput2 myjob myhpsspat mypath'
```

Note: Due to the and operator (`&&`), the function is only executed if the include of `file.sh` was successful.

You can call your function from python with `os.system`:

```
os.system("bash -c '. file.sh && cpput2 myjob myhpsspat mypath'")
```